# Active directory authentication on tomcat by JNDIRealm referrals problem

Tags: authentication, tomcat, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I'm trying to look on on the root of a AD server for users with tomcat5.5 and JNDIRealm, but it seems that there are several referrals to other locations in the whole AD structure and one of the referrals give a `"connection refused"` . With LDAP you can use the option `referrals="ignore"` but this doesn't work if you use AD so you must use `referrals=follow` otherwise you get a `Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s)` exception

Is there a way that I can ignore all referrals to other servers?

current config in a server.xml file:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" debug="99"
        connectionName="CN=root_user,OU= foo,OU= bar ,dc=example,dc=com"
        connectionPassword="hideMe!"
        connectionURL="ldap://****:389"
        userBase="DC=example,DC=com"
        userSearch="(&amp;(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))"
        userSubtree="true"
        roleBase="OU=rolles,dc=example,dc=com"
        roleName="CN"
        roleSearch="(member={0})"
        roleSubtree="false"
    />
```

**Exception:** 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the active directory was corrupt. There where broken referal links. So be sure that the servers are all up and running